# Proguard - keep reflected/introspected classes

Tags: java, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate a jar file which my team has created that uses class reflection. (I think?)

For instance I have the following:

```
Field fProposalPopupFiled = ContentAssistant.class.getDeclaredField("fProposalPopup");
```

How should I modify my library.pro file to make sure the appropriate classes are kept?

I know I will need to use the `-keep` parameter for proguard, but now should I write that line specific to the above example?

Answer (score 1):

ProGuard already recognizes this particular hard-coded construct with a literal string (see the ProGuard manual > Introduction), so you shouldn't need additional configuration.

Otherwise, you would preserve the field with its original name by specifying something like

```
-keepclassmembers class com.example.ContentAssistant {
    com.example.SomeType fProposalPopup;
}
```